# SMS broadcast receiver not working in phone

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have read many questions from stackoverflow but could not find a working code.

My broadcast receiver code:

```
public class incom extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 Toast.makeText(context, "received",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

my manifest code:

```
   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver android:name="com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver.incom">   
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

I have tried many solution.It works in the emulator but not on the phone.can some one help.Thanks in advance.I also tried highest integer value

Comment: If this is running on an Android version >3.0, you need to include an Activity that can be launched first to bring the app out of the _stopped_ state. Otherwise, your Receiver is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
  <receiver android:name="com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver.incom">   
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Change to

```
<receiver android:name="com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver.incom" > 
<intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"
            android:priority="999"
             /> 
</intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Comment: show your log, if there is any error, or try to uninstall and install your application

Comment: no errors in log cat.I reinstalled it.If you have any working tutorial or code.Pls help